# Who is this Marvel Comics character?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification

I am trying to identify this character.

[image]

Comment: What is that issue? Do you have it, or did you find this picture online?

Comment: The issue actually probably came out in 1992-3 according to [Comichron cover price list](http://www.comichron.com/vitalstatistics/mediancoverprices.html).

Comment: @eshier Thanks, fixed that :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I appreciate it!   Gallifreyan, I bought it today; Issue Marvel Comics Presents Wolverine #86

Answer (score 23):

That's Hank McCoy, [Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_(comics)) from the X-men.  Before the blue fur.[image]

From the Wikipedia article about the transformation:

> Hank isolates a "hormonal extract" allowing anyone to become a mutant for a short period of time, and uses the mutagenic serum on himself to disguise his appearance while foiling an attempt to steal his research.[12] He waits too long to reverse the process, leaving him permanently transformed. He grows grey fur, which later turns blue, all over his body and acquires pointed ears, elongated canine teeth, claws, the ability to run on walls and ceilings like a spider, enhanced senses, an accelerated healing factor, and a feral side he struggles to control.

As starpilotsix mentioned, the fur has come and gone (as it did in the movie) which can be seen in the following pic from marvel-microheroes wiki:
[image]
Although the specific uniform isn't pictured here.

Comment: Strictly speaking, judging by the uniform in the original picture, it's AFTER the blue fur, and before the BLUE fur again.

Comment: @starpilotsix I won't argue with that since I've never tried to keep track of all those details.

Comment: Additionally, I am pretty sure this is when he was a part of X-Factor

Comment: Yeah... I remember I first really started recognizing Beast as a character in X-Factor when his "thing" was that the more he used his physical abilities the more his intelligence was weakening (this was cured when he intercepted kiss from a mutant with mutating powers and became blue and smart again).

Comment: The exact issue is [_Marvel Comics Presents_ vol. 1 #86 from October 1991](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Comics_Presents_Vol_1_86), "Just Friends (Part 2)", which features Beast.

Comment: Not what I intended, but on the plus side, anyone who didn't recognize that as Beast probably wouldn't know his tenures in Defenders, Avengers, or X-factor.

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness, that corner-box image was first published in [X-Factor #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Factor_Vol_1_4) (February/May, 1986). As you can appreciate the X of the uniform was red and not white like the one shown in OP's question. I'm not able to determine who was the author of that drawing, probably Bob Layton (who were doing the interiors at that time) or Mike Zeck (who did some of the early covers)

[image: Beast corner box]

In the full cover you can see the costume that Hank McCoy was wearing at that time.

[image: X-Factor 4 cover]

The one depicted in his entry in the Official Handbook

[image: Official Handbook entry]

Beast didn't wear a dark blue + white uniform ever. And at the time of publishing of MCP #86 (October, 1991), he has returned to the blue furry form, that you can see below in a scene taken from that MCP serial drawn by Rob Liefeld.

[image: Beast by Liefeld]